# How to get amount with zero when amount is less than one dollar

Tags: oracle

I have fee column as Numeric(6,2) in my table .I have data 0.46 dollars as Fee.When I used to display in extract with `decode(to_char(fee,   '999,999,999.99'),  .00,   '0.00',   to_char(fee,   '99,999,999.99')) numeric_amt` its coming as .46 but i need to display as 0.46    is it possible to get that.

Answer (score 2):

simply use `to_char(fee, '99,999,990.00')`

refer to [number Format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34570) (Oracle documentation)

Answer (score 0):

try this:
select to_char(fee, '999,999,990.99') as numeric_amt from table;